# Boundary of product manifolds such as $S^2 \times \mathbb R$

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds

Simple question but I am confused.

What is the boundary of $S^2\times\mathbb{R}$? Is it just $S^2$?

What would be the general way to evaluate the boundary of a product manifold?

Thanks for the replies!

Comment: This is locally diffeomorphic to open sets in $\mathbb R^3$, so I don't see how it could have a boundary.

Comment: sure. I read it in a physics paper and the statement confused me. The only plausible way to see $S^2$ as a boundary is as a boundary of the 3-ball $B^3$.

Comment: Also, if $M$ and $N$ are manifolds without boundary, then $M\times N$ has no boundary.

Comment: Probably the physicist is thinking of $\Bbb{R}$ as having "boundaries at infinity" somehow. Unfortunately it's hard to know exactly how without more context...

Comment: Actually, I was looking into the subject of the relation between the Wess-Zumino-Witten model and Chern-Simons theory. If one takes a CS theory with gauge group G on a manifold with boundary and one assumes a pure gauge condition, this gives a 2-dimensional conformal field theory. It is known as a G- Wess–Zumino–Witten model on the boundary. The paper I have checked probably confuses $B^3$ with $S^2\times\mathbb{R}$. Sorry for being unclear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are interested in differentiable manifolds, a variation of what joriki said is still true. If $X$ is a manifold without boundary and $Y$, a manifold with boundary $\partial Y$, then $X\times Y$ is a manifold with boundary $X\times \partial Y$. For more details, you can look at many places, e.g. Guillemin and Pollack *Differential Topology*, Chapter 2.

Answer (score 13):

As others have written, $S^2\times\mathbb R$ has no boundary.

Generally, if $A$ and $B$ are manifolds with boundaries $\partial A$ and $\partial B$, respectively, then $A\times B$ is a manifold with boundary $\partial(A\times B)=(\partial A\times B)\cup(A\times\partial B)$. This is true for manifolds but not for differential manifolds, since the "corners" are homeomorphic but not diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^{n-1}$. For instance, the product of two closed line segments is a closed rectangle, which is homeomorphic but not diffeomorphic to a closed disc. See [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/0910.3518) for an exposition on manifolds with corners.

Comment: a dumb comment ... when you say differential manifolds, do you mean manifolds with corners? the formula you wrote for boundary of product manifolds would work for product of any number of differentiable manifolds, right?

Answer (score 5):

It has no boundary. Let $p=(\theta,\psi,r)\in M:=S^2\times\mathbb{R}$ (think spherical coordinates) then $p$ is an interior point. Indeed $p$ is contained in the open set (a "cube"): $$(\theta-\epsilon,\theta+\epsilon)\times(\psi-\epsilon,\psi+\epsilon)\times(r-\epsilon,r+\epsilon)$$

As an illustrative aside, note also that you can represent M visually as $\mathbb{R}^3-0$. Indeed, if you just associate $r\in\mathbb{R}$ with a sphere of radius $e^r$, then you get the desired visual of $\mathbb{R}^3$ minus the origin. (Note that as $r$ gets bigger so does the radius, and as $r$ gets more negative the radius shrinks.)