# Boundary of $M \times [0,1]$ where $M$ is a smooth manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary

I'm trying to understand this fact that looks very intuitive drawing, but I'm completely stuck trying to prove it formally.

Let $M$ a smoot manifold of dimension $n$ without boundary. Then $M \times [0,1]$ is a smooth manifold with boundary $\partial(M \times [0,1]) = M\times\{0\} \sqcup  M\times\{1\}$. In addition, if $M \times [0,1]$ is oriented the orientation induced on $M\times\{0\}$ and $M\times\{1\}$ are opposite (where I'm identifying $M\times\{t\}$ with $M$).

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: [The boundary of a product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/173951/boundary-of-product-manifolds-such-as-s2-times-mathbb-r) of a manifold without boundary $X$ and a manifold with boundary $Y$ is $X\times\partial Y$

Comment: Okay thanks, what about orientation?

Comment: I don't know right now, possibly you will have to work with the definition of the induced orientation on the boundary.

Comment: You should know how to prove the fact cited by @Javi. The first thing to do is the most straightforward. Did you try writing down the definition of a manifold with boundary and proving that each point in $M\times[0,1]$ is either in the interior or on the boundary? If so, where did you get stuck?

Comment: As for orientation, find the definition of "induced orientation" and try to apply it here. Again, where do you get stuck?

Comment: Thanks for the help @Deane, after a bit of work I was able to prove that  $\partial(M \times [0,1]) = M\times\{0\} \sqcup  M\times\{1\}$ (and more in general the fact cited by Javi). Trying to prove formally that the induced orientation is opposite on the two copies of $M$, I got stuck when I had to write down an outward pointing vector. I read on some books that the two outward pointing vectors should be $[0, \dots , 0, -1]$ and $[0, \dots, 0,1]$, but I'm not able to understand why.